# Xamarin Picker View invalid selection iOS 12

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios12

Below is the sample code already shared in Xamarin docs.

```
 <Picker>
  <Picker.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
      <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
      <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
      <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
    </x:Array>
  </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

When running this code in iOS 12 simulator, it works but when you tap done button, selected item is changed and is assigned to 4th item in the list from the selected item.

For Example, if you select Baboon from above list and tap done button, selected item will be changed to Golden Lion Tamarin.

I am not sure if the issue is only related iOS 12 or not. I am downloading previous version simulators to see.

I have uploaded video recording of simulator [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hXiij21RMGIShaZLs8_RWI2oiMNW_23o), can anyone please guide if it is OS related issue or something else?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any code in place that does something with the selected item or selected index? Does this also happen on Android?

Comment: No, don't have any extra code, let me try the code on a fresh project.

Comment: Fresh project with just the picker seems to work just fine on iOS 12.1

Comment: Tried creating a new project and added only picker, still same issue. 
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community for MAC (Version 7.7, build 1868).

Comment: Can you share the project you created, i'll try running it on my MAC.

Comment: Visual Studio version shouldn't matter. Which version of Xamarin.Forms did you install on your project? I'll try to get my version to you

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/jfversluis/StackOverflowPickerQuestion

Comment: I tried to update the packages, and everything is up to date, but i still face same issue. Tried your code too, it works fine in Android but in iOS still same.

Comment: The problem was with simulator, changed the device and it worked, cleared simulator contents and it is now working perfectly. Wasted so much time because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as mentioned [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1619) (Clearing simulator contents) worked.

The problem was with Xcode simulator, not sure what caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** If you still can not solve the issue,you can use the custom renderer ,and rewrite the event of the button `Done`.

> in iOS project

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class MyPickerRenderer:PickerRenderer,IUIPickerViewDelegate,IUIPickerViewDataSource
  {
    string SelectedValue;

    public MyPickerRenderer()
    {
    }

    public nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        return Element.Items.Count;
    }

    [Export("pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:")]
    public string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return Element.Items[(int)row].ToString();
    }

    [Export("pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:")]
    public void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        Control.Text = Element.Items[(int)row];
        SelectedValue= Element.Items[(int)row]; 
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            SelectedValue = Element.Items[0];

            UIPickerView pickerView = (UIPickerView)Control.InputView;
            pickerView.WeakDelegate = this;
            pickerView.DataSource = this;


            UIToolbar toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;

            UIBarButtonItem done = new UIBarButtonItem("Done", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, (object sender, EventArgs click) =>
                {
                    Control.Text = SelectedValue;
                    toolbar.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    pickerView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    Control.ResignFirstResponder();
                });
            toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] { done };
        }

    }

  }
}
```

> in forms

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace app1
{
 public class MyPicker:Picker
 {
    public MyPicker()
    {
    }
 }
}
```

> in xaml

```
 <local:MyPicker>               
  <local:MyPicker.ItemsSource>               
     <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">                        
       <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
       <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
       <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
       <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
       <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
       <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
       <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
     </x:Array>                    
   </local:MyPicker.ItemsSource>  
 </local:MyPicker>
```

> Note: Here is a [similar issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1619) that you can refer

Comment: The problem was with simulator, changed the device and it worked, cleared simulator contents and it is now working perfectly.

Wasted so much time because of this.